# change to logarithmic form. solve for P.

Tags: logarithms

change to logarithmic form. solve for P.

(2/3)log(R) + 0.05 = log(P)

the base is 10 for both logs.
How do I answer this?

Comment: Note that $0.05 = 0.05\log_{10} 10$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You may use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the readability of the formulas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write this as
$\log(P)
=\log(R^{2/3}10^{0.05})
$.

Comment: So i found that the answer is supposed to be P = 0.05 x R^2/3

Comment: and still i keep getting P = R^2/3 x 10^0.05

Comment: The answer is wrong.

Comment: Wonder why I was downvoted.